# MATLAB Help. Plugging in matrix of variables into existing function

Tags: matlab, variables, calculus

I have an existing function of two variables (x,y) called discriminant defined in the following way:

```
discriminant = xSecondPart * ySecondPart - xySecondPart.^2;
```

Where xSecondPart and ySecondPart are the second partial derivatives of a function f. xySecondPart is the partial derivative with respect to x of the partial derivative with respect to y of the same function f.

I need to print out the values of discriminant at each value of x in the matrix xAns.

The below code is not working...

```
for idx = 1:numel(xAns)
    disp(discriminant(xAns(idx)));
end
```

Hopefully someone can provide a solution. Thank you

Best...SL

Comment: Can you put the definition of the discriminant function?

Comment: ends up being this: 
24*x^2 - 32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the function `discriminant` anonymously, like so:

```
    descriminant = @(x) 24*x.^2 - 32;
```

Then all you have to do is type the following statement in the command line or function you're running:

```
    D = discriminant(xAns)
```

If your function has been defined using the elementwise operator '.' wherever necessary, then the statement above will print out the `discriminant` function evaluated at every element of the matrix `xAns`, regardless of its size or shape.  The values returned will be in the same shape as the matrix `xAns`.  I think that would be the easiest way to solve your problem.